# QAbstractItemModel thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, model-view-controller, model

My implementation of `QAbstractItemModel` is listening to some events, and processes updates in a separate thread.
Processing of an update may lead to layout and/or data change in the Model.
The storage of the data itself is `boost::mutex` - protected, every call of `QAbstractItemModel`'s interface functions (executed, if I understand correctly, in GUI thread), and the update processing functions (in a separate thread) lock the mutex.
Is it okay to emit the signals layoutChanged/dataChanged while locking the same mutex that the data()/rowCount()/whatever may be trying to acquire at the same time?

A piece of code:

```
class MyItemModel : public QAbstractItemModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    void processUpdate(const Update& update) {
        Mservice.post([this, update]() {
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock (Mlock);
            bool willModifyLayout = checkWillModifyLayout(update)
            bool willModifyData = checkWillModifyData(update);
            if (willModifyLayout) {
                emit layoutAboutToBeChanged();
            }
                Mdata.processUpdate(update);
            if (willModifyLayout) {
                emit layoutChanged();
            }
            else if (willModifyData) {
                emit dataChanged();
            }            
        });
    }

    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock (Mlock);
        if (index.isValid()) return Mdata.data(index, role);
    }

private:
    boost::mutex Mmutex;
    boost::asio::service Mservice;
    boost::asio::thread MserviceThread;
    DataStorage Mdata;

}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to store mutex-protected data in the model in the first place. The views wold call `data()` method of the model quite often, even in the lack of much concurrency the overhead of locking and unlocking the mutex might be sufficient.

Comment: If your data is heavy enough, you could encapsulate its management in some `QObject` which would communicate the data changes via signals to the actual models which would store lightweight "views" of the data - for example, if your data stores long texts, the model could contain, say, first 140 characters of each item for the sake of displaying them in the view. For the access to full data (not for views connected to models so that the access doesn't occur that often) you could create your own model API which would retrieve the data synchronously.

Comment: That's indeed the correct way to go. But usage of boost's asio::io_service for processing update is forced by the framework I use.
On the other hand - if the QAbstractItemModel interface functions don't throw, even the original code might work. If the processUpdate() emits layoutChanged() when the GUI thread is in data() call, waiting for locking mutex - nothing bad will happen. data() will return some wrong data(or maybe empty QVariant()), will display it for several moments, then it will process the signal, and very soon will start displaying correct data.

Comment: Qt offers a QReadWriteLock, for example. You can still protect your model with a mutex. When you need to read the model (such as in data()), lock the mutex for Read-access. When you need to update the model, lock the mutex for Write-access (which precludes other threads taking both Read- or Write-access). Overhead of using a mutex may be a concern... but that's not unique to this application. Profile your code to see if it's a problem. If not, keep it simple and use a mutex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer to my own question:
If the Model belongs to a different QThread, then the signals of this model will be connected to view using Qt::QueuedConnection, and it's fine.
But if (by default) the Model belongs to GUI QThread (a.k.a. QCoreApplication::instance()->thread()), the slot of Model will be executed immediately, causing calls to data(), columnCount(), etc, thus, it's not okay.

Comment: It's not *'fine'* per se, see http://blog.hostilefork.com/qt-model-view-different-threads/

Comment: Is there a way to force a model's signals be connected as `Qt::QueuedConnection` even when the model was created on the same thread as the GUI? (the model creates a worker thread that calls the model signals)

Answer (score 1):

`QAbstractItemModel` is [**not** thread safe.](http://blog.hostilefork.com/qt-model-view-different-threads/)

This is mainly because signals across thread get queued.

Imagine the following scenario of a model containing a `QList<int> list;` (ignoring `QModelIndex`):

```
background thread       GUI thread        +         signal queue, abbreviations for readability
[MODEL]                 [VIEW]                      ( )
beginInsertRows(0, 1);   ...                        ( rowsAboutToBeAdded(0, 1) = add(1) )
list << item();          (doing                     ( add(1) )
endInsertRows();        something                   ( add(1), rowsAdded(0, 1) = added(1) )
beginRemoveRows(0, 1);    else)                     ( add(1), added(1), rowsAboutToBeRemoved(0, 1) = rem(1) )
list.removeAt(0);        ...                        ( add(1), added(1), rem(1) )
endRemoveRows(0, 1);     ...                        ( add(1), added(1), rem(1), rowsRemoved(0, 1) = rmvd(1) )
                         rowsAboutToBeAdded(0, 1);  ( added(1), rem(1), rmvd(1) )
                         rowsAdded(0, 1);           ( rem(1), rmvd(1) )
                         possible crash!
```

reason:

in rowsAdded(), the view will sooner or later call

```
model()->data(model()->index(0, 0));
```

This model index is invalid, because the model has no rows anymore.

In the best case it just returns an invalid `QVariant()`.

In the worst case (no defensive checks) the model tries to access `list[0]`.