# Is it possible to force execute main thread (GUI thread) from render thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opengl, qml

We have commands queue which executed in render thread, directly between `QQuickWindow::beforeRendering` and `QQuickWindow::afterRendering`, commands do changes on data model, and when data model changes it immediately notify our custom OpenGL render engine to sync data.

The problem is when data model changes it also notify subscribers who aim to update UI.
But it is error prone approach to update UI from different thread. One way is using `Qt::QueuedConnection`. This is error prone too because when it come executed model may go to far state.

Design is very similar to this [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html).

Is it possible for example update `QStadardItemModel` linked with QML from render thread?

Comment: Why are you executing commands while *rendering* the UI? Just don't do that. Rendering should just draw the UI using the current data/state, not make changes to any data/state.

Comment: Because commands may cause changes in renderer's state. For example, we have command AddBoxCommand. When this command executed it notifies renderer about new object added and renderer reacts for this event by changing his state. Renderer works directly between ```beforeRendering``` and ```afterRendering``` so we can't change his state from different thread while his working. Qt Quick on Windows uses threaded render loop so render thread never locks. Main (Gui) thread initiates syncing with render thread by locking himself. Main thread remains locked while render thread still working.

Comment: We want renderer do his job in Qt Quick's render thread because OpenGL context sharing possible problems. This why we inject commands execution between ```beforeRendering``` and ```afterRendering```.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, you can do it with the [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod(QObject *context, Functor function, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection, FunctorReturnType *ret = nullptr)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod-4) overload of `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`.

For the context you need to pass an object living on thread you want to run your function. For the GUI thread, `QCoreApplication::instance()` is a good candidate.
For the connection type, use `Qt::QueueConnection` or `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`  depending on your needs (weither you need the call to block or not). If you are using `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`, make sure that you are not currently in the main thread (you could do a check and pass `Qt::DirectConnection` if that is the case).

And for the functor, a lambda will do the trick.

In example :

```
qDebug() << "1 main thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();
QtConcurrent::run([] {
    qDebug() << "1 QtConcurrent thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(QCoreApplication::instance(), [] {
        qDebug() << "invokeMethod thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    }, Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);

    qDebug() << "2 QtConcurrent thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();
});
qDebug() << "2 main thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();
```

This outputs:

```
1 main thread 0x1c7c
2 main thread 0x1c7c
1 QtConcurrent thread 0x19ec
invokeMethod thread 0x1c7c
2 QtConcurrent thread 0x19ec
```

Comment: I need to change QStandardItemModel which affined with main (gui) thread and notifies QML view about changes. As far as I learned it is not good idea (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46661870/12847278) to change model from different thread. In our app when command executed it can change domain model. And if it does then event emitted. There are two subscribers for this event. One QStandardItemModel which must reflect this change in own state. And second is our custom renderer engine which use OpenGL context therefore working in Qt Quick render thread.

Comment: It was fine if there a way to execute code in main (Gui) thread even if it was locked for syncing with render thread but seems its impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You could get inspiration from [*Calling Qt Functions From Unix Signal Handlers*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html)

You might have some central data structure, e.g. some `std::deque` containing [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda); let's call it your todo list. That todo list also manages a [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (so two file descriptors).

You would protect that todo list with appropriate `std::mutex` and use `std::condition_variable`

You would synchronize between the render thread and the main Qt thread by using some [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) or [fifo(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), then use (in the main thread) some
[QSocketNotifier](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsocketnotifier.html) for synchronization. The render thread would also [write(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) some byte to that fifo or pipe when adding a closure to your todolist, and the main thread would use `QSocketNotifier` to [read(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) it, then fetch (pop) a closure from your todo list and run it.